# I consider this delete improper

Tags: discussion

[It it possible to avoid kiwi.com's automatic online check-in and instead do it manually by yourself?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/134954/it-it-possible-to-avoid-kiwi-coms-automatic-online-check-in-and-instead-do-it-m/134970?noredirect=1#comment335938_134970) asks if it is possible to avoid automatic check-in on kiwi.com

My answer is that I have done so many times. Below is the answer quoted verbatim:

> Once you identify the specific flight, you can always go to another site, including the airline itself, to book the flight. And of course you can check in with the airline directly as well. I have booked many flights with Kiwi, but I have always checked in on the airline’s website or at the airport.
>
> I have only once paid for a seat assignment, and that wasn’t with Kiwi.
>
> Sometimes, I’ve found Kayak slightly cheaper than Kiwi, and sometimes the airline itself. And more than once, Kiwi has claimed that my charge was declined and asked me to send them images of passport and driver’s license. Big NO on that one! (In each case, I booked with the same card via someone else.).

Someone else who has not even used Kiwi at all thinks that is not an answer. My contention is that when I book on kiwi and do not let them check me in, I am clearly showing that it **is** possible to have them check me in.

Furthermore, I also believe the person who asks the question should be the one to determine whether it answers the question.

Comment: Perhaps I am also a peeve, but I don't know how to link to an answer.  I summarized it above and the full thing is below the question which I did link.

Comment: peeve => plebe (stupid IOS thinks it’s smarter than me).

Answer (score 4):

I think your post doesn't answer the question.

> I have a WestJet Flight LGW-YYC that **I booked using kiwi.com**.

The OP has already used kiwi.com. to book the flight. So your suggestion to use another site doesn't help him in any way

Comment: I clearly stated "I have booked many flights with Kiwi, but I have always checked in on the airline’s website or at the airport."  Shouldn't be very hard to deduce from that "yes, it is possible."  AGAIN, shouldn't the person who asked the question be the one to decide whether it is an answer?

Comment: @WGroleau and was one of this flight with WestJet? Can you find a reference that it works the same way for **all** airlines?

Comment: I know that I have flown WestJet before.  Whether I booked those on Kiwi, I cannot say.  But at least half of the MANY flights (on many airlines) that I have taken since I began traveling four-plus years ago have been booked on Kiwi.  But I ALWAYS check in with the airline and usually print the ticket from them.  Still, I think it should be the one who asked the question to decide it isn't an answer.  Otherwise, I'm saying it is, you're saying it isn't, and neither of us should be the one deciding.

Comment: IMHO your post has some information that could be useful, but it's more a comment than an answer

Comment: @WGroleau I don't think it can reasonably be considered answering the question when you expect people to *deduce* what your answer actually is. But even so, without any advice on *how* to do it, you're at best providing an unhelpful answer.

Comment: This is ridiculous.  The questioner should decide but he isn't reading this and thanks to the silly deletion, probably didn't see the answer either.  'Bye.

Comment: @WGroleau: The OP _commented on_ your answer, and you replied to that comment. I think we can safely assume that he saw it.